Getting error while running npm run dev in react.js
I am learning react.js
I have installed Vite, create project. But, when I run :
npm run dev

I got this error :

That the script is missing.
I have gone through vite repo, search on stackoverflow download nodemon. Somewhere, it was written to download scripts so I run
npm install react-scripts

But still getting same error.
I am beginner can anyone help?

This error is usually related to the package.json file missing the script you're trying to run. Please post your package.json file or check that it contains "dev" script.

it appears your package.json file is missing some scripts. You probably missed some steps while you were scaffolding your Vite project.
Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot:

Verify if you have a package.json file in your project.
Also, confirm that you have the default npm scripts in your Vite project. If they are missing, add the following to your package.json file:



{
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite", // start dev server, aliases: `vite dev`, `vite serve`
        "build": "vite build", // build for production
        "preview": "vite preview" // locally preview production build
      }
}



Once you have them in, you can start your dev server with npm run dev like you did initially.
Finally, you do not need to install react-scripts for your Vite project in this case. You only need to install that package if you're scaffolding a React project via Create React App.
Consult the Vite docs on how to start a Vite project. Here is a vite-react template you can emulate or compare your current setup with.
Cheers!
